# Number of solutions for a system sounds odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had a system of 2 degree equations today in exam, two equations, with 2 variables. I had solved for "x" first, then "y", I cannot remember the system (sorry), however, I got 2 solutions for "x", and this is what i got:

x = 5, or x = -3

by putting "x" in a one of the two equations:

when x = 5, y = 4 or -4, so, the first two solutions were:

{(5,4) , (5,-4)}

now when I've put -3, I got "y" as zero, so i got a one solution because zero isn't either positive or negative; so i got this one extra solution: (-3, 0),

now all I got is 3 solutions in a system of non-linear equations, is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of a 2nd-degree equation will be a parabola, circle, ellipse or hyperbola (or some degenerate version.)  We need to imagine a situation where two of these curves could intersect in exactly 3 points.  For instance takes $y=x^2$, a parabola with vertex at the origin and arms pointing up, and $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$, a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(0,1)$.  Then the arms of the parabola cut the circle at $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$.  The 3rd point of intersection is at $(0,0)$ where the two curves are tangent.

It's sort of rare for two, randomly chosen curves to be tangent, so I'm not sure this counts as "normal".  But it's certainly possible.

Comment: Yeah, it's a rare occasion.